# How to find hot or cool files in blob container

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-files

Is there some way or script to search in your blob container which files are hot or cool to change the to archive?

I have thousands of folders and files and to make this work manually is a nightmare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the blob tier(hot or cool) to archive tier, there is a built-in feature named [lifecycle management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal).

You can just set a rule for your storage account(the rule can be applied for container level or account level or subfolder level as per your need), then the blob service can automatically change the tier(hot and cool) to archive.

Here is an example for container level:

1.Nav to azure portal -> your storage account -> lifecycle management, then click "Add a rule":

[image]

2. In the Details panel -> Specify a "rule name", select "Rule scope"(here, select "Limit blobs with filter" for container level), "Blob type" and "Blob subtype":

[image]

3.In the "Base blobs", specify the settings as below:

[image]

4.In "Filter set", just type your `container name` for Prefix match:

[image]

5.Click "Add" button to save the rule. **Note that** [the rule will be executed after 24 hours](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal#faq).

Comment: thanks this is very useful but my doubt is to know if the files already archived will be charged in my next bill if I use this rule

Comment: @kintela lifecycle management is free. See [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal#availability-and-pricing).

Answer (score -1):

You could change access tier with [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/manage-access-tier?tabs=powershell).

```
#Initialize the following with your resource group, storage account, container, and blob names
$rgName = ""
$accountName = ""
$containerName = ""

#Select the storage account and get the context
$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $accountName
$ctx = $storageAccount.Context

#list the blobs in a container
$blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $containerName  -Context $ctx  
foreach($blob in $blobs)  
{  
    #if tier not equal "Archive"
    if($blob.AccessTier -ne "Archive"){
        #Change the blob’s access tier to archive
        $blob.ICloudBlob.SetStandardBlobTier("Archive")
    }
}
```

---

Another method uses the [`BlobBatch.SetBlobAccessTier`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbatch.setblobaccesstier?view=azure-dotnet) Method SDK in .Net.

```
// Get a connection string to our Azure Storage account.
string connectionString = "<connection_string>";
string containerName = "sample-container";

// Get a reference to a container named "sample-container" and then create it
BlobServiceClient service = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
BlobContainerClient container = service.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
container.Create();
// Create three blobs named "foo", "bar", and "baz"
BlobClient foo = container.GetBlobClient("foo");
BlobClient bar = container.GetBlobClient("bar");
BlobClient baz = container.GetBlobClient("baz");
foo.Upload(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Foo!")));
bar.Upload(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Bar!")));
baz.Upload(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Baz!")));

// Set the access tier for all three blobs at once
BlobBatchClient batch = service.GetBlobBatchClient();
batch.SetBlobsAccessTier(new Uri[] { foo.Uri, bar.Uri, baz.Uri }, AccessTier.Archive);
```

Comment: If I execute this script in my root folder where I have thousands of subfolders and files the change of tier only occurs in the files hoot or cool true?
All the files already in archive tier do will not be affected nor will they have any read operations that are then charged true?

Comment: Not sure whether the blob(Archive) will be charged. After getting the blob, it's better to check current tier.